# removing wrong items from the array list in angular 4

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, slice

I have array of list items like this below

```
L3 - LO
 L7 - LO
 L7 - L3
 % L3 - LO
 % L7 - LO
 % L7 - L3
```

and I am trying to remove with splice method using the below code in angular 4

but some how it is removing other items as well. I would like to remove only the strings that contain L3 and it is removing this Item as well  `% L7 - LO`

```
 if (e.target.value === "L3") {
    debugger;
    let l7L3112Index = this.formulalist.findIndex(item => item.Name === "L7 - L3");
    let l7l32456Index = this.formulalist.findIndex(item => item.Name === "% L7 - L3");
    let l3ls28Idex = this.formulalist.findIndex(item => item.Name === "L3 - LS");
    let l3ls23Idex = this.formulalist.findIndex(item => item.Name === "% L3 - LS");
    let l3Lo87Index = this.formulalist.findIndex(item => item.Name === "L3 - LO");
    let l3lO287Index = this.formulalist.findIndex(item => item.Name === "% L3 - LO");
    this.formulalist.splice(l3lO287Index, 1);
    this.formulalist.splice(l7L3112Index, 1);
    this.formulalist.splice(l7l32456Index, 1);
    this.formulalist.splice(l3ls28Idex, 1);
    this.formulalist.splice(l3ls23Idex, 1);
    this.formulalist.splice(l3Lo87Index, 1);

  }
```

Could any one please suggest any idea on this problem.
Many thanks in advance

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you could just do `this.formulalist = this.formulalist.filter(i => !i.includes("L3"))` to remove all array items that contain `"L3"` in them.

Comment: findIndex and slice then findIndex on sliced list and slice and so on... or sort the indexes and slice in reverse order.... and yes if only L3 need to be removed then why all this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had provided a StackBlitz [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/omit-l3-items-array) in regards with your concern.

If instance your formulaList is an array of object

```
formulaList = [
    { name: 'L3 - LO' },
    { name: 'L7 - LO' },
    { name: 'L7 - L3' },
    { name: '% L3 - LO' },
    { name: '% L7 - LO' },
    { name: '% L7 - L3' }
];
```

You can filter it using Array.filter and Regex

```
this.formulaList = this.formulaList.filter(({ name }) => !name.match(/L3/g));
```

Then it will show you the list without the L3s keyword
[image]

Comment: i need it in reverse actually i need these items `L7 - LO` and `% L7 - LO`

Comment: I edited my answer and the stackblitz demo link as well , now it only shows those 2 you had mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Your approarch won't work because the index of the elements will change once you start removing elements from the list. So you shouldn't use variables to save the indices because they will change after every removal. If all you want to do is remove the items that contain `L3`, then you can filter them out.

Here is an example, assuming you have objects with a `Name` attribute:

```
let formulalist = [
    { Name: "L3 - LO" }, 
    { Name: "L7 - LO" }, 
    { Name: "L7 - L3" }, 
    { Name: "% L3 - LO" }, 
    { Name: "% L7 - LO" }, 
    { Name: "% L7 - L3" }
];
formulalist = formulalist.filter(item => item.Name.indexOf('L3') == -1)
```

The result is the following array:

```
[ {Name: "L7 - LO"}, {Name: "% L7 - LO"} ]
```